# Programmatically building SSIS packages with EncryptSensitiveWithPassword and package-level connection managers

Tags: ssis, msbuild, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to automate deployment of an SSIS project with a saved password for a project-level connection manager. The packages connect to a third-party database that only provides a SQL login, so integrated security isn't an option in this case. I was using [this](http://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/) as a reference since it seems to be for the same use-case. I've got the MSBuild task compiled and working, and an MSBuild project file. I can build and deploy the project through the command line without problems.

**Problem**

When I deploy the ispac file generated through Visual Studio, I can run the packages with no problems. However, when I deploy the ispac that is generated by the MSBuild task and try to run, I get the following validation errors:

> > Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "<>" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
> >
> > Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
> >     An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user '<>'."

If I change one of the packages to use a package-level connection manager to the same server, then the password gets carried over and I can run that particular package.

The connection managers are stored in `.conmgr` files, with a `DTS:Password` node that is marked as sensitive and contains the encrypted password. From what I can tell, the problem arises in the Build task code.  The [code for the build task](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/SSISMSBuild/Project/DeploymentFileCompilerTask.cs) does the following:

- Deserializes the `.dtproj` file to obtain the list of connection manager file paths in the project
- Creates a new `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project` (which, from what I can tell, ties to the generated `.ispac` rather than the `.dtproj` "project")
- For each connection manager file, calls `project.ConnectionManagerItems.Add(<connection manager name>, <.conmgr file name>)`
- Loads the returned `ConnectionManagerItem` via `cm.Load(NULL, <stream of the conmgr file>)`

I'm assuming that somewhere in the last two steps, the password doesn't get deserialized, and the new `Project` gets the connection manager added without a password. I've been scouring the Integration Services Developer's Guide, but it seems more focused on programmatically creating connection managers from scratch, rather than loading existing ones that have data that needs to be decrypted.

**Update**
As per @billinkc's suggestion I unzipped the generated ispac files to compare how the connection managers are saved. The one generated by MSBuild is the same as the one generated by Visual Studio except that it is missing the `DTS:Password` element. That backs up my theory that the code adding the connection manager to the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project` is either not deserializing in or not serializing out the password. I'm way out of my depth in regards to programmability with SSIS though, so I don't know where to go from here. The related documentation** doesn't offer much insight.

** [Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.project.aspx), [ConnectionManagerItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.connectionmanageritem.aspx), [Working with connection managers programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645942.aspx), [Adding connection managers programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136093.aspx)

Comment: Forgive me as I don't work with SQL Logins within SSIS much. Within Visual Studio, if you build the project there, does the ispac get built fine? It might be a matter of trying to discern what the VS built .ispac file has the the msbuild version does not. It might also be a defect in the codeplex task so you might also cross post this question to that list too.

Comment: @billinkc Yeah, I can create the ispac through both MSBuild and VS. The VS version works.

Comment: @billinkc I took a look inside the generated ispac files (didn't realize they were simply zip archives :) and updated my question

Comment: Excellent, then this sounds like a defect for the codeplex folks. It's an interesting question and one I wish I could help on. I concur with the assumption that it's the deserialization of the connection managers but how that factors in is out of my league as well. I'll see if I can pull in @mattmasson He's my Obi-wan Kenobi

Comment: If you add `/verbosity:diag` to your msbuild call, does anything interesting show up? I'm wondering if they don't need something after `var cmXml =` to use the Project.password to decrypt the XML there if the package protection level is the PasswordNeeded was true.

Comment: Feedback from the SSIS dev team: "there was a reason I left that code out. It might have been laziness, but I think I had a good reason I don't remember." via https://twitter.com/mattmasson/status/479435384237985793 "And so i recommend setting the param at catalog level post deployment" https://twitter.com/mattmasson/status/479434501697712128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just couldn't let this go and do it the easy (smart) way, so armed with my knowledge of encryption (little to none) and one line from the MSDN**, I set out to try and decrypt the encrypted element. After a bit of trial and error, I've finally got it working:

```cs
private string DecryptConnectionManagerPassword(string connectionManagerPath)
{
    // Load the xml and get the encrypted DTS:Password node
    XmlDocument cmDocument = new XmlDocument();
    cmDocument.Load(connectionManagerPath);

    XmlElement passwordElement = cmDocument.GetElementsByTagName("DTS:Password")[0] as XmlElement;

    // Create byte arrays with the data we'll need
    byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordElement.GetAttribute("p4:Salt"));
    byte[] iv = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordElement.GetAttribute("p4:IV"));
    byte[] cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordElement.InnerText);
    byte[] password = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ProjectPassword);

    // Create the cipher key
    PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, salt);
    byte[] key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, iv);

    // Decrypt the cipher text
    var csp = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    csp.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    csp.IV = iv;
    csp.Key = key;

    var plainTextBytes = new byte[512];
    var decryptor = csp.CreateDecryptor();
    decryptor.TransformBlock(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length, plainTextBytes, 0);

    // Get convert to a string and extract password
    var plainText = new string(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(plainTextBytes));

    // the decrypted text doesn't come out as valid xml
    // so I use a regex to extract the password. Obviously dangerous.
    var regEx = new Regex(">(.*)<");
    var matches = regEx.Match(plainText);

    return matches.Captures[1].Value;
}
```

And from there, it's simply a matter of setting the `Password` property on the connection manager, and the resulting ispac contains the connection manager with an encrypted password element.

** [Also, for the protection levels that use a password, Integration Services uses the Triple DES cipher algorithm with a key length of 192 bits, available in the .NET Framework Class Library (FCL).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx)

Comment: The `Salt` and `IV` may be missing from the `.conmgr`.  Thus you will need to set the `ProtectionLevel` to `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword`.  In my case, I did this at the project level and a `Salt`, `IV`, and algorithm type `aes256cbc` appeared in the `.conmgr`